# multi dimensional char array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, free

What I am trying to do is create an 2-d array of character strings
The following seg faults instantly, what is wrong?

```
void add2(char***b, char *i)
{
    if (!i) {
       b[0][0] = (char*) malloc(120);
       sprintf(b[0][0], "%s", "hithere");
       b[0][1] = (char*) malloc(120);
       sprintf(b[0][1], "%s", "bithere");
    } else {
       strcat(b[0][0], "\\\\");
       strcat(b[0][0], i);
       strcat(b[0][1], "\\\\");
       strcat(b[0][1], i);
    }

}
void add1(char ***b)
{
 add2(b,NULL);
 add2(b,"one");
 add2(b,"two");
 add2(b,"three");
}

int main()
{
 char **keys[2] = {0};
 int i,j;

 add1(keys);

 for (i = 0; keys[i]; i++)
     for (j = 0; keys[j]; j++)
     {
         fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", keys[i][j]);
         free(keys[i][j]);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare the array keys you are saying to the compiler that you want to work with an array of 2 pointers to pointers to chars and ask it to initialize those pointers to pointer to char to NULL. **All good**.

Then you call `add1()`. **All good**.

Then you call `add2()` and try to put into the first element of `b[0]` the return value from `malloc()`. But the value of `b[0]` is NULL. The NULL was put there in the `main()` function. `b[0]` has no elements!

When you have *arrays of arrays (of arrays ...)* **in the form of pointers** you need to `malloc()` (and `free()`) every level individually.

---

*Edit*

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char **keys[2] = {0};
    keys[0] = malloc(20 * sizeof *keys[0]); /* 20 strings */
    keys[1] = malloc(20 * sizeof *keys[1]); /* 20 strings */

    for (int k=0; k<20; k++) {
        keys[0][k] = malloc(120); /* string with 119 chars + '\0' */
        keys[1][k] = malloc(120); /* string with 119 chars + '\0' */
    }

    /* use k[0][0] through k[0][19] */
    /* use k[1][0] through k[1][19] */

    for (int k=0; k<20; k++) {
        free(keys[0][k]);
        free(keys[1][k]);
    }
    free(keys[0]);
    free(keys[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

I put it all in the `main()` function, but it's the same idea if the `malloc()`s and `free()`s are in their own function.

Comment: so how do i malloc b[0] through b[n]?

Comment: @pxl: actually, to be precise, it should be `malloc(sizeof(char**) * n);`, though in practice `sizeof(char**)` is the same as `sizeof(char*)`. That's the main reason I like to use `sizeof` with the thing I'm allocation memory for: `pointer = malloc(n * sizeof *pointer);`. I don't care if pointer points to an array of structs or a struct with arrays or whatever; the `malloc()` always gets the correct size :)

Comment: well, u can never be too sure... sizeof(char**) would be the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The general procedure for dynamically allocating a 2D array of `char *` is something like this (for any other type T, replace `char *` with the desired type):

```
char ***new2DArr(size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
  char ***newArr = NULL;
  size_t i;
  newArr = malloc(sizeof *newArr * rows);
  if (newArr)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
      newArr[i] = malloc(sizeof *newArr[i] * cols);
      if (newArr[i])
      {
        /* initialize or assign newArr[i][0] - newArr[i][cols-1] here */
      }
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

This assumes you know how many rows and columns you want ahead of time.  Note that you have allocated a table of pointers; you will still have to allocate memory for each string entry, like so:

```
char **myArr = new2DArr(10, 10);
myArr[0][0] = malloc(strlen("Hello, World") + 1);
if (myArr[0][0])
{
    strcpy(myArr[0][0], "Hello, World");
}
```

If you want to add new rows or new entries to existing rows, you're going to have to do some extra bookkeeping.

Here's one example that extends a single row:

```
char **extendRow(char **row, char *newEntry, size_t *numEntries)
{
  char **tmp = realloc(row, *numEntries + 1);
  if (tmp)
  {
    row = tmp;
    row[*numEntries] = malloc(strlen(newEntry) + 1);
    if (row[*numEntries])
    {
      strcpy(row[*numEntries], newEntry);
      (*numEntries)++;
    }
  }
  return row;
}
```

And you'd call it like

```
table[i] = extendRow(table[i], "This is a test", &entryCount);
```

The result is assigned back to `table[i]` in the event that the pointer value is changed by `realloc()`.  I'm doing it this way instead of passing a pointer to table[i] just to keep the pointer gymnastics to a minimum.