# How to Manage a 2 Dimensional Char Array?

Tags: c, arrays, char, 2d

Having gone through dozens of tutorials & programming guides, an answer has not become obvious, hence the post. Please be kind.
The matter at hand is the practical manipulation of double-d arrays of char.: {"aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc",.... M}
The first problem is the declaration an initialisation of such beasts, with view to changing data in the strings "aaaaa", "bbbbb" etc.
The declarations and initialization go as:

```
    char *chararray[M][N + 1] //M & N are set as constant values, the extra 1 for the null terminator.
    memset (chararray, '\0', sizeof(chararray)); //Assuming array bounds remain constant, in the hope that dynamic allocation is not required
```

Assume there is also a string literal defined:

```
    char *copyme; //Has been given a string value well within the bounds of N
```

The problem arises when attempting to use this in strcat or strcat_s (strcpy or strcpy_s similar):

```
    strcat_s (chararray [i][0], N + 1, (char *) copyme);  //i ranges from 0 to M
```

Having not come across any code that handles arrays this way, I did note from this [tutorial](http://pdosnew.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/readings/pointers.pdf) that memcpy is the only way. Correct?

Also, how does one implement John Bode's [General Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527806/multi-dimensional-char-array) when calling the function from Main? (For the sake of brevity, this may have to be submitted as a separate question,)

Comment: `char x[M][N+1];` would be a 2-d array of char. Can you confirm whether you want that, or `char *x[M][N+1]` which is a 2-D array of pointers?

Comment: Want the pointers. _I think_   char chararray[M][N + 1] doesn;t seem to work with strcpy at all.

Comment: So you want to be able to store `M` x `N+1` number of strings? E.g. if `M` is 5 and `N` is 6 then you store 35 strings.

Comment: @M.M Sorry dacfolders eliminated Well no, M strings each of N length.

Comment: No, I really don't think you want a 2D array of pointers. That is clearly not your intent since the second dimension of your array has an "extra 1 for the null terminator". That is, you want an array of character arrays. Not an array of character array pointers.

Comment: It would help if you give some more context about your program. "John Bode's General Procedure" has nothing to do with the rest of the requirements you have stated

Comment: `char chararray[M][N+1] = { 0 };  strcpy( chararray[i], copyme );` - assuming `copyme` points to a string of length `N` or shorter as you have stated.  If you still have trouble then post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) indicating where you are getting stuck

Comment: @M.M Thanks, I'll post as another question re the General Procedure in case the option of dynamic allocation is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant

```
char chararray[M][N + 1];
```

in order then to copy a string you specify the first index

```
strcat_s(chararray[i], N + 1, (char *) copyme);
```

If you have declared it as

```
char *chararray[M][N + 1]
```

then you have a 2-dimensional array of pointers which are NULL and then when you derefence them you get an error:

```
strcat_s(chararray [i][0], N + 1, (char *) copyme); // boom!
```

Comment: Except chararray is incorrectly declared as a 2D array of _pointers_ so you can't copy anything into it, the program might crash and burn.

Comment: He didn't. `char *chararray[M][N + 1]`

Comment: Yep, thanks guys, I edited the question & left the wrong stuff in for all to see. :P

Answer (score 3):

Your initialization is wrong, you are declaring a 2D array of *pointers* not characters. Change it to `char chararray[M][N + 1]`.

Also regarding the comment to memset, you declared the array with static dimensions, so the bounds will never change and you cannot use dynamic allocation if you picked the above method.

Basically you have the following options when using arrays of strings in C:

- In case you are only dealing with read-only string literals, you could use a `const char*` per literal. An array of strings in that case would then be an array of `const char*` pointers.
- Similarly, you could have an array of pointers if the strings are allocated elsewhere, not in your array. You'd have a lookup table.
- If the length of the strings have a known maximum, you could declare it with static dimensions such as `char chararray[M][N + 1]`. This is a 2D array of characters, or if you will: an array of arrays of characters.
- If the length of the strings are unknown, if you need them to be flexible, or if you are allocating large amounts of strings (several hundred), you can allocate them on the heap. In that case you should use an array of pointers, where each pointer is assigned a string through malloc followed by strcpy().

Comment: The confusion in my case was in the description of strcpy & strcat. The first param is       char *_Dst, the second is     constant char *_Src. Both char * as in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbyd7s1y.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) example.